# Selector for View background - XmlPullParserException

Tags: android

I need the background for my `TextView` was changed on touch event, so I have an `TextView` like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv_password_data"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/password_text"
                    style="@style/items_style" />
```

@color/password_text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="@color/title_color"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/text_color"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and I get exception like this:

```
09-15 22:06:02.120: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21006): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
android:color
```

with

```
android:drawable
```

in your selector xml.